# Is the stack frame of a function cleared, or is it left as such on the stack, when we return from the function

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, callstack

I researched on the internet a lot, and it tells me that the stack frame on the stack is cleared (destroyed), when a function returns.

But I suspect, that this is not the case.

I am debugging using the assembly language and my C++ code side-by-side and, from the C++ code, it looks like the stack frame is not cleared, but overwritten when another function is invoked by main().

I looked at the assembly code side by side. And, when we pop a value back into a register, is the value from the stack simply copied back into the register and no further action is taken on the stack. Or, is the value copied into the register and removed from the stack?

C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int* MyFunc(int*);

int main() {
    int* a, b;
    b = 10;
    a = MyFunc(&b);
    return 0;
}

int* MyFunc(int* ptrB)
{
    int inta;
    inta = (*ptrB) * (*ptrB);
    return (&inta);
}
```

Now, when MyFunc returns &inta, a in main gets the address of inta. But this is dangerous, because, if another function is called, after assigning the address of inta to a - dereferencing a after that step (that is *a) will be undefined. Because the content at the address of inta may get overwritten. 
It looks like the address of inta gets overwritten. And it is not the case that the stack frame of MyFunc is cleared (cleaned up, emptied), when MyFunc returns to main. 
I am saying this, because *a might still give the correct result, when a function is called before it.
Am I correct in my assumption that the MyFunc stack frame is not cleared (emptied, destroyed), when the function returns? And simply the stack pointer (ESP) moves to main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data remains in memory. The only parameters changed are stack top pointer (esp) and stack frame base (ebp). Stack frame is a somewhat abstract concept, it is only defined by the values of these two registers. Hence the region above esp is "not visible" even though it may contain data left from previous stack frames

Comment: Yup, that's why uninitialized local vars do in practice usually contain garbage, not zeros, in debug mode builds where every C++ variable really does get its own address in the stack frame.

Comment: @PeterCordes - doesn't MSVC debug build fill uninitialized areas with something like 0xCCCCCCCC ?

Comment: @rcgldr: oh, yes in debug mode I think MSVC does poison stack memory with that bit-pattern (which isn't a valid address, and if executed as instructions is an `int3` trap).  [Why is the stack filled with 0xCCCCCCCC](//stackoverflow.com/q/17644418) and [How to end up with a pointer to 0xCCCCCCCC](//stackoverflow.com/q/3618572).  GCC and clang don't do that by default.  Reading uninitialized vars in optimized builds *sometimes* ends up reading garbage from the stack, so you can sometimes see that with MSVC, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes - the memory fill is only done for debug builds. It's not done for release builds.

Comment: @rcgldr: yes, exactly, that's why in a release build, you can sometimes get MSVC to emit code that reads whatever garbage was in memory before, unlike in a debug build where it poisons it.  (At least by taking a pointer to it and passing it to another function, but maybe just by reading an uninitialized var, if that doesn't get compiled to xor-zeroing like gcc often does, or just reading a stale *register*.)